# Need to store more vehicles per single user_id in django api

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, models

I had customized the inbuilt user model by using abstract user . I made another model vehicle with a one to one relation with user model, which resembles vehicles of each user . But it is storing a single vehicle per user_id. I need it to store multiple vehicles per user. My code is given below -

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  otp = models.IntegerField(null=True)


class Vehicle(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  maker = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
  car_model = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Serializer.py

```
class VehicleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
class Meta:
    model = Vehicle
    fields = ('maker', 'car_model', 'user_id')                                                                      

def create(self, validated_data):
    maker = validated_data.pop('make', None)
    car_model = validated_data.get('car_model', None)
    user_id = validated_data.get('user_id', None)
    instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)

    if user_id is not None:
        instance.user_id = user_id
        instance.save()
    if car_model is not None:
        instance.car_model = car_model
        instance.save()
    return instance
```

Views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def vehicle_add(request):
car_model = request.data.get('car_model')
user_id = request.user.id
serializer = VehicleSerializer(data={'user_id': user_id, 'car_model': car_model})
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    message = "i suceeded"
    return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
else:
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I just need to know how to store multiple vehicles under single user_id. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A django `one-to-one` relationship is exactly as it sounds, it's a relationship from one model to one model. The relationship you're looking for is `many-to-one`. Check out the documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Let me know if you have any more questions!